# Unable to read an email protected by Rights Management Service

Tags: email, security, microsoft-outlook, ssl, tls

My colleague received an email from H company. This email is protected by [Microsoft Rights Management Service](http://www.microsoft.com/rms).

His email client is Outlook Express, and he use POP3 to received it to local disk (the mail is deleted from the mail server). Outlook Express only show a short description about RMS and an attachment named `message.rmmsg`. So I Installed an Microsoft Outlook 2010 on another machine, and forward the whole original email (as an attachment - *SUBJECT*.eml) to his own mail address, and try to read the attachment in Outlook 2010.

At first, I encountered "This service is temporarily unavailable" when connecting RMS server of H company, and after some struggling I found a solution [here](http://blog.csdn.net/mssecurity/article/details/6838210): uncheck IE->Tools->Options->Advanced->Settings->**Check for publisher's certificate revocation** and **Check for server certificate revocation**.

Now, when I try to read this attachment email, Outlook 2010 keeps asking for a Username & Password even if I input the correct mail account of my colleague and password.

[image: Outlook 2010 keeps asking for username & password]

What's wrong? Did I inputed usernamd & password of a wrong realm? Do my colleague need to ask the sender for a username & password to read this email? Or, does the RMS protect email from reading from an .eml attachment (I mean, do my colleague need to ask the sender to send the email again?)?

How can my colleague read the email?

---

update 2014-11-05

I also use my colleague's email address applied an account on [RMS for individuals](https://portal.aadrm.com/) according this article: [View and use files that have been protected by Rights Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn574741.aspx). But still I got same result (keeps asking for username & password) even if I entered password of either RMS accout or email account.

I use wireshark captured the data communicated between RMS server and my computer, the RMS server returns Encrypted Alert.

[image: Screenshot of one packet captured by Wireshark: Encrypted Alert. Content Type: 21]

Answer (score 0):

Reference [Introduction to IRM for email messages](https://support.office.com/en-IE/Article/Introduction-to-using-IRM-for-email-messages-3629182e-0c4f-4d3e-a495-dfa4aea21aa3):

> **Download permissions**
>
> The first time that you try to open an email message that uses
>   restricted permission, you are then connected to a licensing server.
>   **If the licensing server verifies your credentials, it issues a use
>   license, which defines the level of access that you have to a file.**
>   This process is required for each file that uses restricted
>   permission. In other words, **content with restricted permission can’t
>   be opened if the licensing server hasn’t issued you a use license for
>   that content.**
>
> Downloading permissions requires that Microsoft Office send your
>   credentials (which includes your email address) and information about
>   your permission rights to the licensing server. Information that is
>   contained in the message isn’t sent to the licensing server. For more
>   information, read the Privacy Statement.

The message "This service is temporarily unavailable" when connecting RMS server of H company implies that you are unable to get a "use licence". From above:

**Content with restricted permission can’t be opened if the licensing server hasn’t issued you a use license for that content**

> **View messages when IRM isn’t available**
>
> If you must read or open content with restricted permission but
>   Microsoft Office 2010 isn’t available on the computer that you are
>   using, you can use a web browser. **If you use Outlook Web Access (OWA),
>   you can view restricted messages on any browser**.

You can use Outlook Web Access (OWA) to view the restricted messages using any browser.

> Or you can view the messages in Windows Internet Explorer if you
>   download the [Rights Management Add-on for Internet
>   Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=b48f920b-5af0-46b4-994f-2f62582cc86f).
>   However, this doesn’t enable you to reply to, forward, copy, or print
>   the messages. When using the Rights Management Add-on to view
>   messages, attachments that might were sent with the message can’t be
>   viewed.

So, you be able to at least view the message using the [Rights Management Add-on for Internet
Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=b48f920b-5af0-46b4-994f-2f62582cc86f). However this doesn't work for **attachments**.

Comment: Thanks for the information. "*Content with restricted permission can’t be opened if the licensing server hasn’t issued you a use license for that content*" <-- Does this licensing action issued by their server automatically or by a human (say the sender)?  Outlook Web Access is out of options, because we're not using Microsoft Exchange Server, we're using a mail server running on linux OS.  And the sender said the mail has an attachment (word document), so add-on for IE is also out of options.

Comment: As far as I know it's a licence server that responds.

Comment: If it's the license server verifing credentials, then I'm stucked at the screenshot: Outlook 2010 keeps asking for a Username & Password even if I input the correct mail account of my colleague and password. What is the username & password which Outlook 2010 is asking for?

Comment: I use Wireshark to capture the SSL communication data, RMS server returns "Encrypted Alert. Alert (21)" error which I have no idea what's wrong.